# Python Selenium Find By Link Text Issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write some code to automate the bets that I make. I am using Python 3 with Selenium and the Chrome Driver.

I am using the following website.

www.bet365.com

I have managed to make a script to log into the site but I cannot make it select the 'Horse Racing' link. The code I have is as follows:

browser.find_element_by_link_text("Horse Racing").click()

It gives me the following error message:

*NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Horse Racing"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)*

Does anyone have any advice? I have searched online but can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Cant find Horse Racing on home page. Is it only available after you are logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the xpath to find elements by text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()=\"Horse Racing\"]").click()
```

Change the tag "a" to the right one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, can you clarify what you mean by changing "a" to the "right one"? Do you mean the full XPath, which is '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[17]/text()' in this case. Thanks.

Comment: In the xpath description (`"//a[text()=\"Horse Racing\"]"`) it is looking for a tag "//a" that has the text "Horse Racing". And I don't know if the element that you are looking for is an <a> or a <div>, etc... So if the element isn't <a> you need to change it. I don't have an account in the site to test it.

Comment: Ok I didn't read all you had written, from your data it should be ´"//div[text()=\"Horse Racing\"]"´

Comment: Thanks that worked. Much appreciated.